# How do you access the state of a record's workflow using SuiteScript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Is there a way to programmatically access the state of a record's workflow using SuiteScript 2.0?

I have a field on the record that saves the state, but the UI presents a state as part of the Active Workflow display that it seems to maintain itself. Can that be accessed?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a saved search of type Workflow Instance to get the current state, last state and other fields of the workflow but you can't create/load this type of search using SuiteScript since is not supported.